# Printf integer, buffer content initilize with binary 0

Tags: c, printf, buffer

My problem is about printf option, I search, try but without success!

My objective is to print the 4th bytes of buffer like this:
my buffer: "000004B0....."
I try to use :

"%x", "%s", "%d", "%4x"....
I only succeed to obtain "my number = 0".
I succeed to print the value if I shift my pointer off 2 bytes

```
printf ("my number= %x", *(mypointer+2));
```

=> but this is not acceptable.

I suppose, that because 4 first '0' are binary 0.
How can I solve it?

Thanks for your help,
brodbeni

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: specify buffer contents fully and also the expected output, as it's still unclear

Comment: If you want to *fill* with zeros then use `%08x`, `8` will be the size of the print window, `0` means fill with leading zeros, `x` specifies hexa base.

Comment: buffer  contents: SizeOfBuffer on 4 bytes + contents with char.

Comment: To clarify: What do you think the value of the fourth byte is in your example (which I understand to be "0x000004B0") ? What is the value of the third byte? What is the value of byte 0? You might have an "off-by-one" problem (which could lead to an "out-of-bound" problem) and would probably find the concept of "endianess" interesting. If you cannot answer that, make a [mcve] please. And while you are reading help pages, also take the [tour] please.